# The $\cos(\alpha-\beta)$ formula always need $\alpha > \beta$ or not?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm a beginner student study the proof of sum and difference trigonometry formula.

There is a formula that:

$$\cos(\alpha-\beta) = \cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta)+\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)$$

In the tutorial it shows only the case when $\alpha > \beta$

Can this formula be used when $\alpha < \beta$ ? and is the answer mathematically legitimate? and why it is? or why it is not?

please give me very detail and basic step by step explanation. I'm newbie ^^"

Comment: Note that $\cos(x) = \cos(-x)$, so if $\alpha < \beta$, you can replace $\alpha - \beta$ with $\beta - \alpha$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because $\cos x = \cos (-x)$ which can be proven using the unit circle.

Comment: Are you sure your argument leads to a "No"? - Oh, you seemingly answered the title question, which is the opposite of the body question ...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is most definitely valid for $\alpha < \beta$.  This is simple to show.

Assume it's correct for $\alpha > \beta$:

$$
\cos(\alpha - \beta) = \cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta) + \sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)
$$

Consider the following, $\cos(\beta - \alpha) = \cos(-(\alpha - \beta))$.  In this case we have $\alpha > \beta \rightarrow \beta < \alpha$.  But, because the cosine is an even function, i.e. $\cos(-x) = \cos(x)$, we have that:

\begin{align}
\cos(\beta - \alpha) =&\ \cos(-(\beta - \alpha)\\
 =&\ \cos(\alpha - \beta)\\
 =&\ \cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta) + \sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)
\end{align}

It's even easier to see through symmetry via "change of indexes":

$$
\cos(\alpha - \beta) = \cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta) + \sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)\\
\cos(\beta - \alpha) = \cos(\beta)\cos(\alpha) + \sin(\beta)\sin(\alpha)
$$

These two are clearly the same via commutative property of multiplication.  That is, if it's true for $\alpha < \beta$ then it's *also* true for $\beta < \alpha \rightarrow \alpha > \beta$.

I want to point out the importance of the symmetry argument because this would seemingly not hold for a sine function, consider the following, proved for $\alpha > \beta$:

$$
\sin(\alpha - \beta) = \cos(\beta)\sin(\alpha)-\cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta)
$$

Does it hold when $\alpha < \beta$?  Consider the following when $\beta > \alpha$:

$$
\sin(\beta - \alpha) = \cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta) - \cos(\beta)\sin(\alpha)
$$

This is where the fact that $\cos(x) = \cos(-x)$ and $\sin(x) = -\sin(-x)$ is important.  Indeed, if you look at the above $\sin(\alpha - \beta) = -\sin(\beta - \alpha)$ therefore the above "rule" works whether $\alpha > \beta$ or if $\beta > \alpha \rightarrow \alpha < \beta$.

Answer (score 1):

The formula holds for all $\alpha,\beta$. If you only know it for the case that $\alpha-\beta>0$ note that for $\alpha-\beta<0$,
$$ \cos(\alpha-\beta)=\cos(\beta-\alpha)=\cos(\beta)\cos(\alpha)+\sin(\beta)\sin(\alpha)$$
(and of course for $\alpha=\beta$, $1=\cos 0=\cos^2(\alpha)+\sin^2(\alpha)$

Comment: Do you mean that, for example imagine we have cos(60 degrees - 60 degrees) then it will be cos(0 degrees) = 1 = cos(0)^2 + sin(0)^2 = 1^2 + 0^2. Then we get a horizontal line with length 1 (cos(0)) and sin(0) = 0 ?

Comment: @user3270418 No, I mean what I wrote. For $\alpha=\beta=60^\circ$, we have $\cos(60^\circ)^2+\sin(60^\circ)^2=(1/2)^2+(\sqrt 3/2)^2=1/4+3/4=1$

Comment: why you show me the sum formula? I'm asking the difference formula???

Comment: @user3270418 Where do I show the sum formula? I read $\cos(\alpha-\beta)$ in my post.

Comment: in your first comment you says \alpha = \beta = 60 degrees. According to the difference formula, this will result in cos(0) because the \alpha = \beta. it is like cos(x-x). cos(0) = 1. So according to pythagorean theorm it will be 1 = cos(0)^2 + sin(0)^2 = 1^2 + 0^2 = 1. Am I understand correctly? if you put \alpha = \beta = 60 degrees from your first comment into difference formula you will not get the result as you show in the first comment.

Answer (score 0):

Swap $ \alpha , \beta$ . Has anything happened to the result? No. So cos function's argument can be either >0 or <0, cos is an even function, $\cos(-x)=\cos(x),$ or,

$$ \cos (\alpha-\beta)  = \cos ( \beta -\alpha ) $$